# Is there a word for exceptional writing?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

Is there a word to describe the gift of exceptional writing? Or, what would you call someone whose writing is well above average?

Comment: Related, over-the-top writing could be called [purple prose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purple_prose): "so extravagant, ornate, or flowery as to break the flow and draw excessive attention to itself."

Comment: Although it can be a bit cheesy, in English it's very common to use the two paragons: either **Shakespearean or Churchillian**.  (Depending on poetry or prose.)  (Germans might say Neitzschean, Italians might say Danteesque.)  {Or, err, however you form those words in those languages!}

Answer (score 7):

**[wordsmith](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wordsmith)**

> a person who works with words; *especially* :  a skillful writer

---

**[wordsmithery](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wordsmithery)**

> the craft or skill of a wordsmith
>
> **Example usage:**
>
> *In short, his talents: expert wordsmithery , book knowledge, critical elan -- and an ability to crank out literary fretwork very fast.
> [Times, Sunday Times (2004)]*

---

There are phrases like "**author extraordinaire**" and "**wordsmith extraordinaire**" also.

Answer (score 6):

It depends what aspect of their writing was being praised. If it's clarity, you might say *articulate* or *lucid*. If it's brevity, the art of saying the most in the least number of words, you might say *economical* or *succinct*. Or, if their manner of writing is vivid and poetic, you could call it *eloquent* or *stylish*.

Comment: I am looking to give a compliment to a writer that delights the reader on many levels. Mostly the essence or principle of message. No matter the subject it is always delivered in a creative, intelligent, passionate, fun, funny uninhibited way.

Comment: @PetraJoubert: If the words you've written in the above comment accurately describe your response to the writer, then why not use them?

Comment: Thank you, was hoping for some big over the top word. English is not my first languish.:)

Answer (score 2):

To describe a fine writer, I like the phrases *literary artisan* or *literary craftsman*, as in these quotes:

> [Two fellows whose skill I admire greatly today are Michael Chabon — a true **literary artisan**, and William Gibson, also a **craftsman** - though perhaps not as widely recognized as such.](http://bonnettsbookstore.blogspot.com/2013/03/literary-fiction-vs-genre-fiction.html)
>
> [A **literary artisan,** Muckle's carefully crafted descriptions that create the setting of 1980's London allow readers to witness an England on the brink of a globalizing era.](http://www.sixersreview.com/bookreviewlondonbrakes.html)
>
> [Saul Bellow, a master storyteller, **literary artisan** and Nobel Prize-winning author whose work reflected the comic, the tragic, the absurd and the mundane in the personal odysseys of the 20th-century Everyman, died yesterday at his home in Brookline, Mass.](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/articles/A28230-2005Apr5.html)
>
> [Their lead article for this volume is by John Rateliff, and it’s an appreciative and thought-provoking look at Tolkien as a **literary artisan** highly conscious of every word he put to paper.](http://www.mythsoc.org/reviews/tolkien-studies-6/)
>
> From a paper entitled, *Lincoln: A Literary Craftsman* – Judged on their own merit, many of the Lincoln items would hardly be worth inclusion among the works of America's greatest writers. But the best of his expressions cast a kind of glow over the rest. And practically all exemplify **literary craftsmanship** of a high order — nothing fancy, just strong declaratory sentences and always *le mot juste.*

I think of *wordsmith* as more of a person who is good at putting words on the paper quickly and prolifically, but not necessarily in a manner that would be considered fine writing. And then there's this [Urban Dictionary definition](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wordsmith), which supports my thought that the word has come to have this kind of meaning:

> *wordsmith* — One with the ability to effortlessly string together words, no matter their actual meaning, in an instance and in such a way it brings a smile to the faces of those listening, sometimes often laughter or tears of admiration for having heard someone with such an amazing skill. Often one to spawn many a catch phrases or wicked new taunts and subtle insults, as well as song lyrics, raps and strange and often disturbing stories that make little sense.
>
> The wordsmith's job is to make up bullshit on the spot.

Answer (score 1):

**Clarity and readability, to bring about communication and delight**

The object of the writer is that of any other artist. It is to communicate a message and ultimately to delight the recipient; whether that be the listener, the viewer or the reader.

Comment: Beautifully said! Thx